# Can't attach VMDK to Virtual Machine (Thumb Drive mounted as Raw Disk)?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, virtualbox

I'm trying to boot from a thumb drive in VirtualBox on Windows. The thumb drive has a copy of Windows 7, and its bootable.

I created a VMDK using `vboxmanage` according to [Boot your USB Drive in VirtualBox](http://agnipulse.com/2009/07/boot-your-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/). The VMDK is backed by the thumb drive.  I'm at the point I am trying to attach the virtual disk to the virtual machine. When I do, the operation results in ***VERR_ACCESS_DENIED***:

[image]

And:

```
Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: Medium
Interface: IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Since I am getting an *Access Denied* error, I added *EVERYONE, Full Control* to `usb.vmdk`. But that has not helped.

Why am I getting an *Access Denied* error, even though *EVERYONE* has *Full Control*?

How does one attach the VMDK to the system?

Comment: Also there is some software P... (I don't know the exact name, maybe it is plpbt) which is small bootable "system" which can automatically boot your USB if BIOS/VM does not provide such a boot option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens if you forget to run things as Administrator.

When you're doing the **vboxmanage.exe** bit, you must make sure you run the Command Prompt as Administrator.

Then, when you actually go to launch VirtualBox, you also need to make sure you run it as Administrator. That's because RAW access to the *USB device itself* requires Admin rights (permissions on your usb.vmdk file is not the problem - the error message is a bit misleading in that respect).

NOTE: Under Windows 8/8.1, even if you log in as Administrator, and even if you have disabled UAC, *you must still explicitly grant admin rights to an application* by right clicking the relevant shortcut then clicking the **Run as administrator** menu item. That's Windows 8 for you.

NOTE 2: If you're still stuck after trying the above, follow the advice of Korkman on the VirtualBox forums: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=38914#p175089

Good luck, let us know how you go :-)

Comment: Thanks Misha. I gave up on this method as it seemed like a dead end. VrtualBox is a turd in areas like booting from a thumb drive and [sharing data between a host and guest](http://superuser.com/q/851958/173513). Now I see why they give it away (the broken features would probably make it illegal).

Comment: The same problem occurs in Windows 10. Even if you take ownership of the vdmk file and the drive it points to has the proper permissions, it still doesn't work.

Windows permissions system is broken!  Why don't people just call it what it is instead of dancing around the issue.  Microsoft is a big boy!

Comment: Can't get it working in Win10. :(

Comment: Run VirtualBox as Administrator worked for me @NathanOsman

Answer (score 0):

## VERR_ACCESS_DENIED Error Even When Started With Admin - Kill Background Processes and Close Disk Manager

In addition to running vboxManage as Admin and starting Virtualbox GUI as Admin, before starting Virtualbox GUI:

1. Verify there are no other instances of Virtualbox or other processes using the disk. Background backup programs are often the culprit. Download Sysinternals [ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), open up, type `ctrl-shift-f` (or in menu `Find->Find Handle or DLL`), type "HardDiskX" where X is the physical drive number, and press `Search`. Kill (or restart which may be safer and enough to release the disk) any process other than "System" that is using the disk.
2. CLOSE Disk Manager if you had it open to get the device number to create the VMDK file. Disk Manager will lock the drive so Virtualbox will not be able to access it.